# Check mocking call on array of objects

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to verify if a method in all objects of an array is called once.

I am using powermockito and currently this is done by iterating through the objects

```
for(Layer layer : layers){
 verify(layer,times(1)).reset();
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to check if all objects in the array are called with the method once ? i.e. without iteration

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you cannot check a condition for all objects in a collection or array without iteration. Maybe it is possible to hide this information behind a Mockito method call, but nevertheless, Mockito will do an iteration to check the condition for all your objects.

You could create a helper method doing the iteration if you wanted to look your test code to look more self-explanatory.

Or you could use `Stream.forEach(Consumer)` if you were using Java 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: Would be handy if they had provided that in the API